# Column missing after Pandas GroupBy (not the GroupBy column)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using the following source code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Daily_to_weekly.csv', keep_default_na=True)

print(data.shape[1])
# 18

# Create weekly data
# Agreggate by calculating the sum per store for every week
data_weekly = data.groupby(['STORE_ID', 'WEEK_NUMBER'], as_index=False).agg('sum')

print(data_weekly.shape[1])
# 17
```

As you may see for some reason a column is missing after the aggregation and this column is neither of the GroupBy columns (`'STORE_ID', 'WEEK_NUMBER'`).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `data.groupby(['STORE_ID', 'WEEK_NUMBER'], as_index=False).sum()`, without the `agg`.

Comment: Otherwise, provide a minimal, runnable example in your question, please. See [mcve].

Comment: @coldspeed thank you for your comment. No it does not work with `.sum()` either.

Comment: my guess is that the missing column is not numerical, so it is ignored.

Comment: Include in your question the output of data.info().

Comment: You are right @YilunZhang, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've run in to this problem numerous times before. The problem is panda's is dropping one of your columns because it has identified it as a "nuisance" column. This means that the aggregation you are attempting to do cannot be applied to it. If you wish to preserve this column I would recommend including it in the groupby.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns

Comment: Sometimes even the groupby columns are dropped as well. The solution seems to be a custom function passed to agg instead of a summary stat like mean or sum. This custom function must deal with null values.